# Why Java utilizes both Collection and Collections classes to provide different things

Tags: java, collections

In many places Java utilizes the approach to have both, for example, `Collection` and `Collections` class.

`Collection` is interface, it defined some methods.
`Collections` class also provide some method. 
Why didn't they choose to place all methods inside the interface?

because the names are too puzzled word. `Collection` is like `Collections`.
I know the historical reason. like `interrupt()` and `interrupted()` , because java must fit to old version, the methods' names are likely, make developer difficult to write and read.
But the collection framwork must have reason in this way.

Comment: You need to reword your question.

Comment: Your question is not a good fit here. Only the creators of the API can accurately answer it, and they are unlikely to do so.

Comment: There are a lot of hysterical ... er, I mean historical reasons for this.  In many cases the classes were developed separately (and at separate times) and then coerced to behave similarly, using various techniques.  There is no doubt that if the designers were starting over "clean" there would be fewer such "warts" on the architecture.

Comment: i have reword my question, and i think i find a reason. because some methods are not born to a kind of class. and in some case method must use instance, only class can not support.like the asLifoQueue() in Collections, must have an instance

Answer (score 3):

For starters, an interface cannot have static methods.  Note: until Java 8.

Arguably, some of the static methods of `Collections` should have been made instance methods of `Collection`, but that would create a lot of "clutter".  Plus, extra work for implementations not derived from `AbstractCollection` etc.